# assigning variables via input() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, input, variable-assignment

Is it possible to assign variables via the input() function in Python 3? In my case I am trying to give the user the option to assign objects to variables in a list.

My idea would be to type the variable assignement directly into the argument of the input function:

```
board=[f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f,f8,f9]

input(f1=some_Object)

print(board[0])
```

Result for `print(board[0])` should then be `some_object`. The same procedure should then also work for f2,f3...f6.

However this does not work, it produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Christian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Tic Tac 
Toe.py", line 1, in <module>
board=[f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6]
NameError: name 'f1' is not defined
```

so im wondering if there is a way to do it in
Python.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "this does not work".

Comment: You mean something like `board[0] = input()`?

Comment: i added the error that i mean with 'it does not work' .@Scott Hunter

Comment: @timgeb No, I want the user to be able to specify wich element of the list should get assigned to the object

Comment: @ChristianSinger The error in your code is in the first line: you're trying to make a list of variables that you have not defined.

Comment: @fedterzi I changed the list into a blank list and now Python tells me that the keywords in the brackets of the input function cant be expressions (wich i was apparently trying to enable the user to do). Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to assign a variable with `input()` is the following:

```
my_variable = input("Some prompt ")
```

If you then want to see the output to convince yourself, you can add:

```
print(my_variable)
```

This will output back at you whatever you enter.

In your case you can do

```
board[0] = input("Enter a value: ")
```

Comment: The problem that i have with this, is that it specifies wich elemten of the list should get assigned to the value, however i want this to be up to the user. He should be able to choose.

Comment: To understand, you want the user to both specify the value and the position in the list?